# MongoDB db.dropDatabase() dropping all but one collection

Tags: mongodb, database

I get a status of { "dropped" : "FLIS", "ok", 1 }, but then I run a "show collections" and see that one collection remains in the database and it contains all records previous to the drop.

This is super frustrating. I need to copy fresh data over from a staging database, but the only way to get the data there is with a copyDatabase. If i run the copy, it will duplicate records in my remaining collection. Since there is no implicit rename functionality in MongoDB (yet), I am stuck with my main database and a collection that I cannot remove

I have also tried to remove the collection individually with db.collection.drop(). I get a "true" back, but it still exists afterwards fully populated.

Help! Thank you!

Comment: This is weird..
you can optionally choose to remove those db files from your storage directory. Make sure you remove the .ns file too ( i.e. all <database-name>.* files )

Comment: what version of mongoDB is this? what version of the shell? (you can do this at the shell: > db.version() and > version() first is server second is shell version.  Can you cut and paste your actual shell session showing the drop and then the existence of the db/collection again?  What's the name of the collection that won't go away?

Comment: btw, what do you mean by "there is no implicit rename" - there is explicit rename: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/renameCollection/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments guys. I tried again in 10 minutes and everything worked. Strange. @asya-kamsky I am using 2.4.3 as output by db.version(). Also, i meant no implicit rename for a database (without copying)...however I didn't try just renaming the collection. Hope I don't have to work around this again.